# How to calculate time difference in php or laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have two time like total worked time and total duty time. eg.

```
$dutyTime= 182:00:00; ("H:i:s")  
$workedTime= 178:10:28; ("H:i:s")
```

my question is that how can i get difference between this two time;

**Expected Output**

```
$duration=03:49:32; ("H:i:s")
```

i tried `strtotime()` but i takes upto 24hrs.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php this may help you

Comment: How about converting to seconds, subtracting and converting back to hours?

Comment: @tuckbloor it takes only 24hrs or 12hrs format. whereas i have sum of time slots(i.e. sum of month or week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$start  = date_create('21:21:05');  //start time
$end    = date_create('10:20:00'); // end time
$diff   = date_diff( $start, $end );

$date= $diff->h.':'.$diff->i.':'.$diff->s;
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime($date));
?>
```